# How to schedule an email using twilio sendgrid in django?

Tags: django, email, twilio, sendgrid

I'm currently building an app which contains email sending to multiple users which i'm able to do but i want to add a functionality which schedule's an email, for instance I'm using `sent_at` method as you can see below:-

settings.py

```
EMAIL_FROM = 'EMAIL'
EMAIL_API_CLIENT ='XXXXXXXX'
```

views.py

```
import json
from sendgrid import SendGridAPIClient
from django.conf import settings

message = Mail(from_email=settings.EMAIL_FROM,
               to_emails=selectedphone,
               subject=subject,
               html_content=editor)
message.extra_headers = {'X-SMTPAPI': json.dumps({'send_at': 
                         FinalScheduleTime})}
sg = SendGridAPIClient(settings.EMAIL_API_CLIENT)
response = sg.send(message)
if response.status_code == 202:
     emailstatus = "Accepted"
elif .....
else.....
```

I've also tried `message.extra_headers = {'SendAt':FinalScheduleTime}` but it's not working either.

Comment: What do you mean when you say it is not working? What is happening? Does the email send straight away or not at all? What is `FinalScheduleTime` in your example code? What is the `message` object you are referring to?

Comment: message = Mail(from_email=settings.EMAIL_FROM,
                                                   to_emails=selectedphone,
                                                   subject=subject,
                                                   html_content=editor)
This is the message object which im referring to add headers and the FinalScheduleTime is im getting from frontend for scheduling the email.
To answer your first question, the code that i refer here it is not working in my case so im finding different combination(solutions) to work.

Comment: To answer your second question - the mails are sending straight away not with the time we have scheduled.

Comment: Is this using the SendGrid library to send the mail or are you sending via Django’s email integration?

Comment: i already mentioned that im using 'TWILIO SENDGRID', anything else?

Comment: Twilio SendGrid is a product which can be used in many ways. In Django, for example, you can configure the built in email library with SMTP details or you could use the SendGrid Python library that calls the REST API. It is unclear to me from what you have shared so far how you have configured your application to send email. If you could elaborate I would have a better chance of helping you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the FinalScheduleTime is of the datetime object. The sendgrip api accepts the UNIX timestamp according to the documentation. [You can check it here](https://docs.sendgrid.com/for-developers/sending-email/scheduling-parameters)

Hence to convert your datetime object into unix time stamp, you can use the time module of python.

```
scheduleTime = int(time.mktime(FinalScheduleTime.timetuple()))
```

Also, replace the message.extra_headers with message.send_at.

Hence, your final code will look like:

```
import json
import time
from sendgrid import SendGridAPIClient
from django.conf import settings

message = Mail(from_email=settings.EMAIL_FROM,
               to_emails=selectedphone,
               subject=subject,
               html_content=editor)


scheduleTime = int(time.mktime(FinalScheduleTime.timetuple()))
message.send_at = scheduleTime

sg = SendGridAPIClient(settings.EMAIL_API_CLIENT)
response = sg.send(message)
if response.status_code == 202:
     emailstatus = "Accepted"
elif .....
else.....
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an official blog by Twilio on **Using Twilio SendGrid To Send Emails from Python Django Applications** - https://www.twilio.com/blog/scheduled-emails-python-flask-twilio-sendgrid

Also here are, [official docs](https://docs.sendgrid.com/for-developers/sending-email/scheduling-email#:%7E:text=There%20are%203%20easy%20ways,the%20hour%20or%20half%20hour.)

Comment: first of all it is not for django it's for flask and still we've tried the same as per document.